# c# ¿Como cambiar la forma en la que se navega con las flechas del teclado en un MenuStrip vertical?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Mi pregunta es acerca de un MenuStrip, tengo uno en mi aplicación de winforms, el mismo tiene **dock = left** y **LayoutStyle = VerticalStackWithOverflow**, por lo que se ve como este más o menos: [image: https://imgur.com/a/GIq6J]

En mi caso tiene 7 opciones y una imagen sobre cada texto, crearlo es sencillo, lo que necesito ahora es que la navegación dentro del mismo sea intuitiva pero no encuentro como cambiar los eventos de las flechas del teclado.

En este momento el MenuStrip se comporta como si fuera horizontal, por lo que las flechas de arriba y abajo abren las opciones, en lugar de navegar entre una opción y otra, y las flechas de izquierda y derecha son las que navegan entre opciones, necesito cambiar eso, ¿Es posible?

No adjunto código porque basta con crear un mdi y añadirle el MenuStrip con algunas opciones y ponerle las propiedades como ya mencioné antes para que quede vertical a la izquierda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No solemos poner enlaces, puedes agregar la imagen que necesitas en la misma pregunta, así la misma no se pierde en caso que el link se rompa!!